# Error connecting Raspberry Pi W to Kinesis Video Streams

Tags: c, openssl, raspberry-pi, amazon-kinesis

I'm following Amazon's guide to connect a Raspberry Pi W to their Kinesis Video Streams service from the link below:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/kinesis-video-streaming/kinesis-video-raspberry-pi-getting-started.pdf

However, when I run the sample application using this command:
./kinesis-video-demo

The console outputs the following and ends the process:

Begin streaming video...

INFO - Initializing curl.

Illegal instruction

I believe the application ends due to an openssl error which is a dependency for the "kinesis-video-demo" app. The openssl github page says that an "illegal instruction" may occur from the no-sse2 parameter when installing openssl as seen in the 'INSTALL' file from their github page.
https://github.com/openssl/openssl

Is there a certain way I need to install openssl on a Raspberry Pi W for this application to work?

Comment: Hey, did u ever manage to find a solution to this? I'm on a Raspberry PI Zero W and have the same problem. Been stuck on this for over a day now. If you figured out what the problem is and could share your solution I'd be super grateful :)

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working on the Raspberry Pi W, however I did the same exact setup for a Raspberry Pi 3 model B and it worked instantly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Same here, couldn't get it to work on RPI W (even after fudging the C code to use less memory) but have since bought a RPI3 and it's working nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

I had got this same issue. However, after changing to Raspberry Pi 3 model B, it is working good.